# How to make the second line of the figure caption start below the word "figure"?

Tags: captions, indentation

How to make the second line of the figure caption start below the word "figure"?

so is my caption.

I don't want this indentation that occurs for the subtitle. I would like the second line to start aligned with the word "figure"

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: It depends on the document class and packages.  If this is for a publication, don't change it.  If this uses the caption package, you need [format=plain].

Comment: What you want is the default in the standard article class, so the answer with these clues is "don't do whatever you're doing" that however, it could be what you *must* to do, if you are using a template of a thesis or the document class of a journal, for instance.